# Filtrar RecyclerView con Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

Buen dia, tengo un problema al momento de filtrar datos obtenidos de `MySQL` en un `RecyclerView` con un `Spinner`, el problema radica en que cuando tengo datos en todos los filtros del `Spinner` si me filtra bien todo el contenido pero cuando en al menos un filtro del `Spinner` no hay datos se queda con el ultimo filtro que se hizo pero debería de quedar en blanco para que se me comprenda de mejor manera mostrare lo que tengo:

Tengo un Spinner en el cual manejo los estados de un pedido:

```
private Spinner spEstados;
```

Para que se filtren los datos cada vez que yo selecciono una opción del `Spinner` utilice el método `setOnItemSelectedListener` de la siguiente manera:

```
spEstados.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            
            obtenerReportes();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Y como ven dentro de `onItemSelected` agrego el método que obtiene los datos en en `ReciclerView` para que se filtre cada vez que se seleccione una opción diferente del `Spinner`

Dentro de mi metodo vale la pena aclarar 2 cosas:

1. Utilizo la siguiente sentencia: `reportes = new ArrayList<>();` esto para que cada vez que se filtre se obtengan los datos que corresponden y no se agreguen al final
2. A mi `URL` le paso como parámetro la selección que se ha hecho del `Spinner` "gIdEstadoCliente"

Y eso es lo que tengo por el momento como repito todo funciona bien nada mas que cuando no hay datos en el filtro el `RecyclerView` no se borra y se queda con el ultimo filtro que se selecciono.

Espero que se haya entendido la pregunta si necesitan algún otro tipo de código por favor pedirlo de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto se puede realizar facilmente validando por la posiciòn del elemento en el Adapter.

Comment: Hola @Elenasys me podrias brindar un ejemplo por favor, gracias

Comment: Te doy una pista, el tercer parametro de onItemSelected() es "position" en base a esto puedes validar para solucionar el problema.